# Context value is null after page refresh in one component

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

I am working on nextJS application with socket.io. I have initialize the socket in a context and sharing the instance across component. But for one of the component, I am getting null after page refresh though socket instance getting reinitialized.

socket.context

```
const SocketInstance = ({ children }) => {
    const socketRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = io();
        socketRef.current = socket;
       console.log(socket); // getting socket instance after refresh
    },[])

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider
            value={{
                socket: socketRef.current,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

### Component

```
  export default function Home({ onlineUsers }) {
    const { socket }= useContext(SocketContext)
    const [ users, setUsers ] = useState(onlineUsers || 0);
    const [ tab, setTab ] = useState('home');

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log({socket}) //getting null
      socket && socket.on('user', (count) => {
       setUsers(count)
      })

       /* return () => {
         socket.off('user')
       }  */
    },[])
    return (
      <Layout>
        <div className="container">
          <Head>
            <title>Movie Fight</title>
            <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
          </Head>
          <p className="fixed top-2 right-2">Online : {users}</p>

        </div>
      </Layout>
    )
}


export async function getServerSideProps(){
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/online');
  const onlineUsers = await res.json();
  return { props: { onlineUsers } }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useEffect in child component are run before parent and hence the socket is home was being used before it was available.

In such cases instead of storing socket in refs, you should store them in state and add dependency of socket to useEffect

```
const SocketInstance = ({ children }) => {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = io();
        setSocket(socket);
    },[])

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider
            value={{
                socket,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

---

```
export default function Home({ onlineUsers }) {
    const { socket }= useContext(SocketContext)
    const [ users, setUsers ] = useState(onlineUsers || 0);
    const [ tab, setTab ] = useState('home');

    useEffect(() => {
      socket && socket.on('user', (count) => {
       setUsers(count)
      })
    },[socket])
    return (
      <Layout>
        <div className="container">
          <Head>
            <title>Movie Fight</title>
            <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
          </Head>
          <p className="fixed top-2 right-2">Online : {users}</p>

        </div>
      </Layout>
    )
}
```

Comment: got your point. Its working. Would you mind if I ask you to review the project code?

Comment: Wouldn't that be too much ?